# Append input box using jquery in opposite(bottom to top) direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append input box when we click on add icon(+), while if we want to remove the appended input box we click on remove(X) button. But here i want the appended input box to appear before the static input box i.e. in opposite(bottom to top) direction.

[Here is the image of what i want to display:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiGOn.png)

```
Html:

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
     <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_field_button" title="Add field"><img src="images/plus.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Code:

```
        var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_field" title="Remove field"><img src="images/close.png"/></a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });
```

Comment: `append()` will append the element at the end. Use jQuery's `prepend()` method.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia - please add this as a answer if you wish to. I feel its correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add input before clicked button's input please find below snippet for more information

```js
var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).prepend('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_field" title="Remove field"><img src="images/close.png"/></a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
     <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_field_button" title="Add field"><img src="images/plus.png" /></a>
</div>
```